# Вывод полей в представлении в drupal 7

Tags: drupal, html, css

Делаю сайт-портфолио на drupal7,использую фильтр isotope filter, изображение и заголовок выводится хорошо,но когда пытаюсь добавить новое поле вывода(например ссылка куда-либо) то ничего не выводится. В чем может быть проблема?

http://www.subjay.ru

Answer (score 1):

Кроме добавления поля в типе материалов, надо добавить его вывод в `Views` (`/admin/structure/views`). Если это сделано, то нужно смотреть настройки. Попробуйте переключить формат в представлении на неформатированный список (Unformatted list). Если там будет отображаться, то надо смотреть настройки вашего фильтра.